# RTMP stream MP4 with FLVPlayback Component

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, video-streaming, osmf

I'm having to change a video from an ollllddd project. It was built using the AS3 FLVPlayback Component. The video back then were FLV and streamed fine from out limelight server.

The new videos I received are h264 MP4s and are NOT streaming. Has anyone been able to successfully STREAM mp4 files using the FLVPlayback component?

I never use this component anymore. I have since moved onto OSMF player and I can stream MP4s no problem

Edit: This program is rather large and is highly dependent on the FLVPlayback component so swapping it out isn't an option right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The URL is way different. Should have known because its the same format as the OSMF player. The URL has to be formatted like so:

```
rtmp://youserver.llnwd.net/xxxx/mp4:xxx/u/clients/xxxx/vov/vov_low_version2'
```

note the location of `mp4:` rather than in front of or after *just* the filename